# Is there any time limit when we access a database?

Tags: java, jdbc

Well. I just recently come into conclusion about this one. Is there any time limit when we access the database? To be precise, MySQL database accessed through Java's JDBC and driver provided by MySQL?

To know more precisely what happen, I give you more detail:

So I got a website that actually provide RESTful webservice, which also backed with Kitty-Cache for caching, because some computational is expensive to do. I run the project, and I access all the api address from browser, and all is well.

Strange is when I did not shut down my computer, and today I access again, the address that has something to do with database (MySQL) just error, internal server error, and the error is caused by NullPointerException in a place where it should not happen. I stopped the project, run it again, access the same address, and it displayed the data.

Is there any time limit? How we can refresh the database connection? I think I will try to re-connect it again, but I am not sure how.

Code:

```
java.sql.Connection conn = null;

try {
   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
   String conStr = 
       "jdbc:mysql://" + this.dbHostname +
       ":" + this.dbPort + "/" + this.dbName;
   conn = DriverManager.getConnection(conStr, this.dbUsername, this.dbPassword);
   this.isConnectingSuccess = true;
} catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
   throw new IllegalDbCmdExecution(cnfe.getMessage());
} catch (SQLException sqle) {
   throw new IllegalDbCmdExecution(sqle.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Can you show us some code, or at least jdbc statement?

Comment: Read about autoReconnect and wait_timeout properties for JDBC. Setting autoReconnect to true and/or increasing wait_timeout from default 8 hours to more should help.

Comment: This will also be related to how you connected to the database.  But yes, I would suspect that there is a timeout for inactive connections

Comment: I read about autoReconnect, and I am not interested in using it... I would like to setup the connection manually, rather. But how?

Comment: And, Btw. @Shishir, for autoReconnect, that means you have to append the URL and have something like jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sakila?profileSQL=true&autoReconnect=true, is it?

Comment: That's right. There might be another way via config/ini file but I am aware of only URL way.

Comment: I recommend using a connection pool.

Answer (score 0):

Well. I manage to solve this problem. What I do is that, previously when I want to query database, I invoke execute() method. Now, execute() method is a final method:

```
public final void execute() {
  preExecuting();
  executing();
  postExecuting();
}
```

And then I declared preExecuting and postExecuting as a void method, and of course, overridable:

```
public void preExecuting() { }
public void postExecuting() { }
```

And then executing as abstract method, and thus, this method has to be implemented:

```
public abstract void executing();
```

So, later I need to do something with executing, which actually cut code previously in execute() into this executing method. In further class, I override the preExecuting with code to test the connection by doing "SELECT 1" and test if it throws an SQLException. If it is, then I need to re-establish the connection.

As simple as that. :)

Answer (score -1):

Check out the [wait_timeout](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout) parameter for my.ini and also check for interactive_timeout

Comment: I don't want to modify anything default, I guess I prefer to keep it 8 hours. Only when there is an SQL request, and not in connection, I would like to re-establish the connection, manually.

Comment: Use `timer` or `thread` to check whether the `con==null` or not. If it is `null` then re-establish the connection.